# Non-SA role restoring database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I'm reading Books Online correctly, a user can restore an existing database if they're the DBO of that database; the actual words are:

> If the database being restored does
>   not exist, the user must have CREATE
>   DATABASE permissions to be able to
>   execute RESTORE. If the database
>   exists, RESTORE permissions default to
>   members of the sysadmin and dbcreator
>   fixed server roles and the owner (dbo)
>   of the database (for the FROM
>   DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database
>   always exists).

Unfortuantly, this doesn't seem to be exactly correct or there's a subtlety I'm missing. For a specific database, I'm trying to get this to work but when the user does a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` to get the files in the backup file, we get the error:

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

It's a slightly confusing error message as at this point all we're doing is trying to read the backup file, not create, nor even restore an existing, database; so I can only assume SQL Server attempts to do a permissions check before allowing any `RESTORE` command to execute.

Now BOL doesn't mention any extra permissions needed, so am wondering which is correct, or am I missing a subtlety in the text. Whilst I don't doubt the error messages accuracy, what do I really need to do to get a user who is `db_owner` of a database to be able to restore that database, without elevating their permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a change in this area in and above SQL Server 2008 compared to SQL Server 2005 and below. Some of it is documented in the below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx

Comment: Ah - an entry in BOL I missed; cheers.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need membership of the db_creator role - basically, SQL Server can't tell whether you are db_owner of a database that is yet to be restored! I see what you are saying though...